# Writing to a specific line in a file, VB2008

Tags: vb.net

Is it possible to use an array to write muliple text boxes into multiple lines in a text file without changing the rest of the text file? I used this:

```
'Write co-ordinates into KML file
Dim line() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines([filepath]\A.kml")
line(19) = A2.Text
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("[filepath]\A.kml", line)
```

But it would replace the content beneath it.

Thanks

Comment: modifying and writing an XML file as if it was a text file is...odd.  If Line 19 is `<item>ziggy was here</item>` and you replace it with "John was here" from A2.Text, you will trash the file.

Comment: Is tehre another way to add co-ordinates into a file for Google Earth?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Dim List As New List(Of String)
Dim Writer As New StreamWriter(<filepath+filename>)
Dim Reader As New StreamReader(<filetoread>)

Do Until Reader.EndOfStream
    List.Add(Reader.ReadLine())
Loop

List(19) = A2.Text

For Each s As String In List
    Writer.WriteLine(s)
Next

Writer.Close()
```